# How do I convert a basic reference type variable to a primitive one?

Tags: java

I have two variables: `Double x` and `double y`. I would like to assign x's value to y, but obviously there is an "incompatible types" error that is shown in a simple `y = x` expression. `y = (double) x` does not work properly either. How can I solve this if it's generally possible?

Comment: Those are not incompatible types, so both `y = x;` and `x = y;` should work. Either you are using a very old version of Java from before auto-boxing/auto-unboxing, or you have declared your own class named Double (which you should not do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `doubleValue()`

```
double y = x.doubleValue();
```